# How EXACTLY does recursion work in this case?

Tags: java, recursion, stack

I am new to this forum and I hope that I don't make any mistakes.
Here's my question. I think I understand the basic principle of recursion and its implementation, yet I have problems to understand the EXACT steps the computer is doing when executing a recursive code.

Here's an example:

public class Main {

```
public static void MyAlgorithm (int [] A, int l, int r ) {
    if (l<r) {
        int m = (l+r)/2;
        MyAlgorithm(A, l, m);

        for (int i = l; i<=r; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }

        MyAlgorithm(A, m+1, r);
    }


}
public static void main (String args[]) {

    int [] A = {1,2,3,4};

    MyAlgorithm (A, 0, 3);
}
```

}

The output is: 12123434

But how does this exactly work?
At first, the code calculates m as 2. It then performs the method again on the subarray (1,2) and puts this on a stack. Then it does it again, takes the half and puts 1 on the stack. As far as I understand the issue, it then stops, pops 1 from the stack and prints it. But when does it put the 2 on the stack separately? And when exactly does it start the recursion part with the other half?
I simply cannot really understand how the computer is executing the single steps and how it "knows" when to start calling the other half of the array recursively. 
I hope you understand my question and I am grateful for every response!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Whether the method call is recursive or not doesn't change how it works. Each execution is executed one after the other. If the instruction is a method call, then all the instructions in the method are executed.

Comment: Use paper and pencil and try to follow up the execution.

Comment: Thanks, JB Nizet. So the recursion is continuing to go through the code and initially "ignores" the recursive call? But then why is the loop not printing 1,2,3,4 at first, since i=l is 1 and r is 3 during the first call?

Comment: Because prior to printing 1,2,3,4, there is a recursive call to MyAlgorithm(A,0,1). See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execution call will be something like this

```
MyAlgorithm(A,0,3) 
    (l < r : true)
     m = (0+3)/2=1
     MyAlgorithm(A,0,1) 
            (l < r : true) 
            m = (0+1)/2=0
            MyAlgorithm(A,0,0) 
                (l < r : false) return

            loop from l=0 to r=1
            System.out.println(A[0]);
            System.out.println(A[1]);

            //MyAlgorithm(A,m+1,r)
            MyAlgorithm(A,1,1) 
                (l < r : false) return

    loop from 1=0 to r=3
    System.out.println(A[0]);
    System.out.println(A[1]);
    System.out.println(A[3]);
    System.out.println(A[4]);

    //MyAlgorithm(A,m+1,r)
    MyAlgorithm(A,2,3)
        (l < r : true)
        m=(2+3)/2 = 2
        MyAlgorithm(A,2,2)
            (l < r : false) return

    loop from 1=2 to r=3
    System.out.println(A[2]);
    System.out.println(A[3]);

    MyAlgorithm(A,3,3)
            (l < r : false) return      
return
```

This leads to answer: 12123434

Comment: Thanks for the great reply, I think I get this code now!